# How to add formula which is sum of $Quantity and display at the bottom? How to auto numbered list when data is fetched?

Tags: php

```
mysql_select_db("fyp",$connect);
$sql="SELECT * FROM `table 1` WHERE Year='$Year'";

//query the database
$query=mysql_query($sql,$connect);

    while($HData=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

        $Country=$HData['Country'];
        $Method=$HData['Method'];
        $Type=$HData['Type'];
        $PLine=$HData['PLine'];
        $PType=$HData['PType'];
        $Year=$HData['Year'];
        $Quarter=$HData['Quarter'];
        $Revenue=$HData['Revenue'];
        $Quantity=$HData['Quantity'];

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Country</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Method</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Type</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$PLine</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$PType</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Year</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Quarter</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Revenue</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Quantity</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: `auto numbered` means ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query=mysql_query($sql,$connect);
$sum_quantity = 0;
$i = 1;
while($HData=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

    $Country=$HData['Country'];
    $Method=$HData['Method'];
    $Type=$HData['Type'];
    $PLine=$HData['PLine'];
    $PType=$HData['PType'];
    $Year=$HData['Year'];
    $Quarter=$HData['Quarter'];
    $Revenue=$HData['Revenue'];
    $Quantity=$HData['Quantity'];
    $sum_quantity += $Quantity;
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td align='middle'>$i</td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'>$Country</td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'>$Method</td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'>$Type</td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'>$PLine</td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'>$PType</td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'>$Year</td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'>$Quarter</td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'>$Revenue</td>";
        echo "<td align='middle'>$Quantity</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
     $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    $series = 1; // define serias for display automated numbers in table
    $sumQty = 0; // create variable for storing sum of all qty
    while($HData=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {

        $Country=$HData['Country'];
        $Method=$HData['Method'];
        $Type=$HData['Type'];
        $PLine=$HData['PLine'];
        $PType=$HData['PType'];
        $Year=$HData['Year'];
        $Quarter=$HData['Quarter'];
        $Revenue=$HData['Revenue'];
        $Quantity=$HData['Quantity'];
        $sumQty += $Quantity; // add qty in sum of qty

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$series</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Country</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Method</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Type</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$PLine</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$PType</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Year</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Quarter</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Revenue</td>";
            echo "<td align='middle'>$Quantity</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $series++; // increase series by 1
    }
    echo "<tr><td colspan='10' align='middle'>$sumQty</td></tr>"; // this will display sum of total qty in footer tr
```

Comment: If this answer helped. Please don't forget to mark this answer as correct answer. As, it will help other user to find this answer easily @christinano